# Can you beat Pool of Radiance: Ruins of Myth Drannor with only one character?

Tags: pool-of-radiance-ruins-myth-drannor

Create one character instead of four, play the game to its good ending. NPCs can join your party for a quest if it is indispensable but you must ditch them at the first opportunity.

Is the game still beatable?